# Aragon DAO dapp cannot make transaction

Tags: solidity, dao, installation

I'm trying to develop a DAO dapp based on the Aragon App on GitHub. (https://github.com/aragon/app)
I use the env. example variable and include the keys as in the attached screenshot. I've managed to connect to my wallet, but unable to make transactions (like creating proposal or creating new dao). The original env.example only has the API for Goerli. I use sepolia instead of Goerli here. There are a few API that I don't have such as the VITE_GATEWAY_IPFS_API_KEY. I'm not sure if this is the main cause behind my problems.

I'd like to know how can we get the VITE_GATEWAY_IPFS_API_KEY and fixed this problem.

Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]